# WebService in IIS exception after some time of inactivity

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, exception, spring.net

I have two web-services in my project. `SecondService` uses `FirstService` through Spring.NET.

Here is a fragment of configuration file:

```
<object id="SecondServiceClass" type="SecondService.SecondServiceClass">
    <property name="FirstService" ref="FirstServiceClass"/>
</object>
<object id="SecondService" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceExporter, Spring.Web">
    <property name="TargetName" value="SecondServiceClass"/>
</object>
<object id="baseClientService" abstract="true">
    <property name="ProductTemplate">
        <object>
            <property name="Timeout" value="10000" />
                <!-- 10s -->
        </object>
    </property>
</object>
<object id="FirstServiceClass" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceProxyFactory, Spring.Services" parent="baseClientService">
    <property name="ServiceUri" value="http://localhost/FirstService/FirstService.asmx"/>
    <property name="ServiceInterface" value="Services.First.IFirstService, ServiceLayer"/>
</object>
```

After some time running (about 2-10 hrs) I get this exception from `SecondService`:

> Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException
>   Exception message: Error creating context '/secondservice': Could not load type from string value 'SecondService.SecondService'.

The services are possibly idle for some time before the exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Write a ping method (a simple method retuning nothing) for your webservice and call it periodically!